# laravel named resources not working properly and removes the dots from the beginning

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

*problem*:

I'm trying to add  name prefixes to my route groups:

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->prefix('dashboard')->name('dashboard')->group(function () {
    
    Route::get('', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboard']);

    // other routes
    Route::resource('estates', EstateController::class, ['names' => '.estates' ])->except('show');
    // other routes
});
```

it removes the `.`. (it should be `dashboard.estates.index` , etc ...)

```
| POST      | dashboard/estates                       | dashboardestates.store          |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates                       | dashboardestates.index          |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates/create                | dashboardestates.create         |
| DELETE    | dashboard/estates/{estate}              | dashboardestates.destroy        |
| PUT|PATCH | dashboard/estates/{estate}              | dashboardestates.update         |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates/{estate}/edit         | dashboardestates.edit           |
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

*test 1*:

how ever if I pass an array option to `names` it works fine with dots `.`.

```php
Route::resource('estates', EstateController::class, ['names' => ['index' => '.estates.index'] ])->except('show');
```

```
| POST      | dashboard/estates                       | dashboardestates.store          |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates                       | dashboard.estates.index         |
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

*test 2*:

```php
// web.php
Route::resource('estates', EstateController::class, ['names' => '.estates.' ])->except('show');
```

routes list:

```
| POST      | dashboard/estates                       | dashboardestates..store         |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates                       | dashboardestates..index         |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates/create                | dashboardestates..create        |
| DELETE    | dashboard/estates/{estate}              | dashboardestates..destroy       |
| PUT|PATCH | dashboard/estates/{estate}              | dashboardestates..update        |
| GET|HEAD  | dashboard/estates/{estate}/edit         | dashboardestates..edit          |
```

expected: `dashboard.estates..index`, etc

got: `dashboardestates.index`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it all to as follows:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function () {
    
    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'dashboard'])
        ->name('dashboard');
    
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/dashboard', 'as' => 'dashboard.'], function () {
        Route::resource('estates', EstateController::class)->except('show');
    });

});
```

The output of the above for named routes will be `dashboard.estates.{method}`.

This could be simplified (i.e. not repeating or nesting certain things) the named route for the dashboard were to be `dashboard.index` rather than `dashboard`.

Comment: there is a root named `dashboard` inside this group. it will change route to `dashboard.`. what's the solution?

Comment: @alien Not sure what you mean, I don't see a route named `dashboard`. Check [here for an example](https://phpsandbox.io/n/tiny-resonance-aepa-xgipq)

Comment: edited the post. look at the first code example. there is a main page for the dashboard. also it's not clean to write duplicate code. how ever it's like the best way around. and the main quesion remains: why laravel removes the `.` from the beginning of the names and how to stop it.

Comment: ok I accepted your answer. please accept the edit. how ever I think should be better answers to this problem.